# How to send wifi and local servers over usb to computer

Tags: wifi, usb, raspbian-lite, wifi-direct

So what I want to do is send wifi and local servers over usb to computer.

So the raspberry pi connects to the internet fine and is hosting a server on it. What I then want to do is connect it to my pc over usb, **like how tethering to pc works with a mobile device.** So then my computer access the internet and the local server on the pi.

Thank you,

Please comment if you have any more questions.

Comment: why do you want to use a USB connection? ... why not Wi-Fi or ethernet?

Comment: Because wlan0 on the pi can't connect to the internet and be a hotspot and I would have to get an ethernet adapter.

Comment: AFAIK this is only possible with the Zero models and the Pi-4, because USB is not symmetrical: A device is either a master or a slave.  Normal PCs, including Rpis, are normally masters and you cannot connect a master to a master.  However, if configured correctly the Zero can be a slave ("gadget mode") using it's USB 2 jack and the Pi-4 using USB-C.  See, eg: https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2019/11/02/pi4-usb-c-gadget/